# Remove Yoast Breadcrumb Last Item On Single Pages Only

Tags: wordpress, yoast

i got this code from researching and trying to modify it but no luck. I want the last item in yoast breamcrumbs not to appear on single pages only

```
 if ( is_single() ) {
 /*Remove Last item in Yoast SEO Breadcrumb */
 function adjust_single_breadcrumb( $link_output) {
 if(strpos( $link_output, 'breadcrumb_last' ) !== false ) {
    $link_output = '';
 }
 return $link_output;
 }
 add_filter('wpseo_breadcrumb_single_link', 'adjust_single_breadcrumb' ); 
 };
```

I tried adding if is single in between the function and also this

```
 if(strpos( $link_output, 'breadcrumb_last' ) !== false && is_single) {
```

unfortunately, the whole breadcrumb disappears.

Answer (score 1):

with this code, you can remove post title in single page.

```
add_filter('wpseo_breadcrumb_single_link_info', 'remove_post_title_wpseo_breadcrumb', 10, 3);
function remove_post_title_wpseo_breadcrumb($link_info, $index, $crumbs)
{
    if (is_singular() && isset($link_info['id']))
        return [];

    return $link_info;
}
```

---

**Updated:**  In the latest version above code does not work perfectly.
for this reason, I removed the last item with regex:

```
function getBreadcrumb() {
    if ( function_exists( 'yoast_breadcrumb' ) ) {
        ob_start();
        yoast_breadcrumb( '<p id="breadcrumb" class="meta-info">', '</p>' );
        $breadcrumb = trim( ob_get_clean() );

        if ( is_singular() )
            $breadcrumb = trim( preg_replace( '/ ' . WPSEO_Options::get( 'breadcrumbs-sep' ) . ' <span class="breadcrumb_last" aria-current="page">(.*)<\/span>/i', '',
                $breadcrumb ) );

        echo $breadcrumb;
    }
}
```

And call the function anywhere you want:

```
<?php getBreadcrumb() ?>
```

Comment: Worked well for me! Thanks, Parsa.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Parsa I found the **wpseo_breadcrumb_links** filter, worked just fine, and you can add any extra validation inside

```php-template
    <?php add_filter("wpseo_breadcrumb_links", "wp_guide_wpseo_breadcrumb_links_filter");
    function wp_guide_wpseo_breadcrumb_links_filter($crumbs) {
        if (is_singular("post")) {
            unset($crumbs[2]);
        }
        return $crumbs;
    }
    ?>
```